Cloudformation for UsagePlan with Method Throttling unabel to parameter the resource and method
In below API usage cft I unable to parameterize the api resource and meythod.
ApiUsagePlan:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan"
    Properties:
      Throttle:
        RateLimit: 1000
        BurstLimit: 5000
      ApiStages:
      - ApiId: !Ref MyApiGatewayApi
        Stage: !Ref MyApiStage
        Throttle:
         "/hello/world/GET": <--- How to get this parameterised
          RateLimit: 50
          BurstLimit: 50

I am getting below error instead
esource handler returned message: "Invalid patch path '/apiStages/sk4knm4yub:ppe-auth/throttle/!Ref MethodName/burstLimit' specified for op 'replace'. Must be one of: 
[/name, /description, /productCode, /quota/period, /quota/limit, /quota/offset, /throttle/rateLimit, /throttle/burstLimit, /apiStages/<apidId:stageName>/throttle/<resourcePath>/<httpMethod>/rateLimit, /apiStages/<apidId:stageName>/throttle/<resourcePath>/<httpMethod>/burstLimit, /apiStages/<apidId:stageName>/throttle] (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 5ff7c212-bb69-4284-9a4b-6fa2305d5945)" (RequestToken: 7ae87cae-198e-01d7-ef3e-afdfa2a6472b, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

expecting to apply the input parameter for resource and method


How to get this parameterised

Its not possible with CloudFormation. You would have to developed per-processing procedure of the template before uploading or using some macro or a custom resource.

The error occurs because CloudFormation does not support directly parameterizing API Gateway resource paths (/hello/world) and HTTP methods (GET) inside the Throttle configuration. But, you can use the !Sub function to dynamically construct the path based on parameters.
This is an example:
Parameters:
  ApiResourcePath:
    Type: String
    Default: "/hello/world"  
    Description: "The API resource path for throttling"
  HttpMethod:
    Type: String
    Default: "GET"
    Description: "The HTTP method for the API resource"

Resources:
  ApiUsagePlan:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan"
    Properties:
      Throttle:
        RateLimit: 1000
        BurstLimit: 5000
      ApiStages:
        - ApiId: !Ref MyApiGatewayApi
          Stage: !Ref MyApiStage
          Throttle:
            !Sub 
              - "${ApiResourcePath}/${HttpMethod}"
              - {
                  ApiResourcePath: !Ref ApiResourcePath,
                  HttpMethod: !Ref HttpMethod
                }:
                RateLimit: 50
                BurstLimit: 50

Now with this approach we can the Throttle key dynamically resolves to something like "/hello/world/GET" during stack creation.
